# Permutation groups and Sylow's theorem

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose we have primes $p$ and $q$ such that $q|(p-1)$, how do we show that $S_p$ contains a subgroup of order $pq$?

Comment: Assuming such a group existed, it would have to be non abelian, because otherwise that would indicate an element is $S_p$ with order $pq$, which can't happen (partition of $p$, LCM of which is $pq$). I still don't know how to go about proving this though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say $S_p$ acts on $Z/pZ = \{0,1,\dots,p-1\}$. Write $p-1 = qk$.

Let $\sigma$ be the permutation defined by $\sigma(x) = x+1$. $\sigma$ is a cycle of order $p$. It generates a cyclic subgroup $H$ of $S_p$ of order $p$.

Let $l$ be a generator of the multiplicative cyclic group $(Z/pZ)^{*}$ of order $p-1$. Now let $\rho$ be the permutation defined by $\rho(x) = l^k x$. Then $\rho$ has order $q$, and generates a cyclic subgroup $K$ of order $q$.

We have $\rho \sigma \rho^{-1} = \sigma^{l^k} \in H$. This shows that $K$ is contained in the normalizer of $H$. From this it is easy t conclude that $HK$ is a subgroup of order $pq$.